# Set CSS style using Javascript and cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have two checkboxes in a popup. The first checkbox is to agree to the data policy. The second checkbox is for saving the agreement in cookies to never show the popup again. For this I want to save a CSS style in a cookie.

How can I save the styles for never show the popup again?

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

$(function() {
  $('#submitbtn').on('click', function() {
    if (document.getElementById("checkSocialwall").checked) {
      wrapper.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display = "block";
    }

    // cookie set
    if (document.getElementById("checkCookies").checked) {
      // here i want so declare a cookie for do display: none to the wrapper
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Don't store CSS in cookies. Instead store a boolean flag and then check the cookie on page load and hide/show the popup as needed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you send a example please?